# How to make common reusable css for almost every common things in web design?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

How to make common reusable css for almost every common things in web design? Like Horizontal and vertical form with javascript validation, Horizontal and vertical navigation with or without dropdown, multiple horizontal boxes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a more high-level answer than you're hoping for, but I highly recommend you view Nicole Sullivan's slides on what she calls ["Object-Oriented CSS."](http://www.slideshare.net/stubbornella/object-oriented-css)

Answer (score 0):

There are many css frameworks out there such as

- Blueprint css
- YUI css

These frameworks offer reset of css, and several standards on how you do your layout. Blueprint css offers plugins which is where you might find what you are looking for.